# How to edit Vim syntax highlighting for HTML files?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting

Where would I start in trying to get MacVim to look like Sublime Text 3? I am using the theme [**Tomorrow-Night-Eighties**](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/colors/Tomorrow-Night-Eighties.vim) on both text editors.

---

**HTML file in MacVim:**
[image: MacVim]

**HTML file in Sublime Text 3:**
[image: Sublime Text 3]

Comment: First, copy `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim` to `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim`. Then edit that file and your colorscheme to your liking as per `:help syntax`.

Comment: @romainl thank you!!!!!